# Magento2 Quote Issue when edit and create order of same customer on multiple tab

Tags: quote

In Magento2 when I am editing some customer order as ADMIN on one tab and at a same time open other tab to create Order of that same customer it updated quote(products) of that order which I was trying to Edit.

I am expecting not to update quote information of customer whose order I was trying to edit.